# How to copy assets from library to a jniLibs with gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, copy

I see a week ago, that Android Studio doesn't copy jniLibs automatically if your project is not a type of com.android.application. So, I'm developing an SDK which has a type "com.android.library" with a folder with files inside assets folder of the library, so I'm looking for a way to copy this files to the jniLibs folder of the app with Gradle, but I didn't find anything, and I don't know if it is possible.

Comment: Afaik, in a library if there are .so files in the appropriate `src/main/jniLibs/ABI` folder, they get copied into the resulting app that includes the library. What kind of library / assets are you trying to include and where do they come from? Would probably help if you could explain a little what your setup is and what the desired result is

Comment: I'm doing a normal, library, but If I put a jniLib folder in my library, when I add to my project like implementation the folder is not copied.

Comment: Did you inspect (or unzip) the apk / bundle? It's not copying files into the app directories, buildtools take files directly from their library location, aar files, ...

Comment: Yeah, the libs are not copied, I'm looking for the folder lib inside data with device explorer of android studio, and it's not copied. Other projects of type com.android.application in gradle, has this structure copied, but mine with com.android.library not.